# gdal_translate and warping of image using c#

Tags: c#, gdal

I am trying to reproject an image, using gdal, is there any c# wrapper I can use to do it?

the sample I am just seeing online are using the tools of gdal. I wanted to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from V2.1, gdal added support for the use of gdal utilities such as gdalwarp & gdaltranslate as library api.
With the new api you can use gdaltranslate with all supported drivers including MEM driver.

You can find more info here:
https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/rfc59.1_utilities_as_a_library

Also please note there is a known bug with the c# binding for gdalwarp api incase you need to use it too. Bug & work around link:
http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2017-February/046046.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are C# bindings for GDAL.

https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/GdalOgrInCsharp

Comment: Thanks Logan, but ive already looked into that. Still cant find how to do, gdal_translate using the API. I need to warp the image aswell

Comment: @makoyc gdal_translate is an executable binary.

Comment: yes, its a executable binary, what i was looking is to do how the translate is doing with the api.

Comment: @makoyc You need to compile C++ code to make GDAL work. This includes the C# bindings as far as I can tell. If you are already compiling GDAL core, why not use the tools that can be built in that same process?

Comment: Yes, it looks like that the only way, but our requirement here is to use gdal c++ or c#(If possible). Im a c# and this c++ is killing me.  on c# i was able to do the coordinate transformation and tried using the AutoCreateWarpedVRT. But still no luck, I think i am missing the gdal translate part. gdal site samples shows  GDALCreateGenImgProjTransformer and GDALSuggestedWarpOutput to use, but cant seem to find it on c#

Comment: is there subch formula to determine or calculate scale x, y pixel and lines when warping an image?

Comment: @makoyc That is another question entirely. Ask it on [gis.stackexchange.com](http://www.gis.stackexchange.com) and you will get an answer.